# I need some help in the rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys this is my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/store'
  get 'home/chat'
  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

and this is my controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def chat
  end

  def store
  end
end
```

and i am linking my three pages index.html.erb, chat.html.erb, store.html.erb which are in the home folder
like this in application.html.erb

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><link_to "Home","index.html></li>
  <li><link_to "Buy Games","store.html"%></li>
  <li><link_to "Watch Videos","#"%></li>
  <li><link_to "Ask The Experts","chat.html"%></li>
</ul>
```

now the problem is that my root which is localhost:3000 is working fine but when i open any other link like chat through application.html.erb then the address bar is something like this "localhost:3000/chat.html.erb" but my location of file is in view/home/chat.html.erb same thing happens when i open any other link
so what should i do to make the routing work also i have tried putting home\chat.html in the link tag in apllication.html.erb it works but when i go back it adds another \home in the address bar

also my background images which i put in the inline style are displaying but when i open any other webpage like chat.html.erb then the inline css background images are not uploading

Comment: Please see the link_to example: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: you have to add resource path like this `link_to "home", root_path`

Answer (score 1):

You need to

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/home/store', to: "home#store", as: :store
  get '/home/chat',  to: "home#chat", as: :chat
  get '/home/index', to: "home#index", as: :index
  root 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

your application.html.erb

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Buy Games",store_path %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Ask The Experts", chat_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure to look over [stack overflow's markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you with styling your post in order to make it readable. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Okay, so it looks like you don't quite have the right syntax for specifying your links using rails' `link_to` helper with erb. The correct syntax is:

```
<%= link_to "my link", your_route %>
```

But it looks like you typed:

```
<link_to "Home","index.html>
```

You missed a closing " and didn't properly open or close the erb tags. So the correct syntax would be:

```
<%= link_to "Home", "index.html" %>
```

Then finally for all your links:

```
<li><%= link_to "Home", "index.html" %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Buy Games", "store.html" %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Watch Videos","#" %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Ask The Experts","chat.html" %></li>
```

be sure to look at the [rails guides](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) regarding the link_to helper for more information.

Hope that helps and good luck!